# VBScript Execute not working for variable, but does for string

Tags: vbscript, eval, execute

I've got code to build variables based on a string using Eval and Execute.
But for whatever reason, Execute is leaving the variable empty when I try to set it to a variable. But works fine if I set it to a string manually

This DOES NOT work, Gives an empty box:

```
For j = 0 To 2
    name = "alias_" & j
    val = "test"
    Execute(Eval("name") + "=" + val)
    msgbox(Execute(Eval("name"))
Next
```

This DOES work, shows "test" in the msgbox:

```
For j = 0 To 2
    name = "alias_" & j
    Execute(Eval("name") + "=" + "test")
    msgbox(Execute(Eval("name"))
Next
```

So Execute doesn't seem to like the variable here. What's even stranger, in my VBSEdit debugger, I can see the locals, and it creates a local variable called "test" instead of setting the value to the alias_j variable. Totally confusing me now.

Comment: Don't construct variables like that. Ever. If you need indexed variables: use arrays. That's what they were invented for.

Comment: Actually I would use dictionaries.. and will use dictionaries..  was having another vb-ism with dictionaries so I was trying something more creative with arrays, but didn't want iterative arrays. But I got dictionaries working properly now so this is defunct. Still good info... people are too afraid of 2 of the most powerful functions.

Comment: You're confusing "afraid" and "wary".

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create variables named `alias_0` thru `alias_2` and assign a value to each? If so, this should work. It assigns the value `test0` to `alias_0`, `test1` to `alias_1`, etc.:

```
For j = 0 To 2
    name = "alias_" & j
    val = "test" & j
    Execute name & " = val"
    MsgBox Eval("alias_" & j)
Next
```

Comment: Yes. that did it. Thanks! I think the issue was the "+" was trying to do math.. as I was wrong in my original post.. it only worked with a variable if it was a number. But your way works fine with strings. Thanks!

Comment: I _just_ updated my answer a few seconds ago. Take another look. And, yes, always use `&` in lieu of `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: @Bond Personal opinion here but I try to avoid & as a concatenation operator whenever I can. It hides the conversions. Debug enough of other peoples scripts and it gets really annoying. 

Obviously I still use & when i'm just working out an idea. Or when on the RARE times I won't know the type. Otherwise it's + with CStr() of the Cxxx family of conversion functions.

Maybe this is just my mindset coming from a typed/strongly typed C/C++/C# background But i prefer TELLING VBScript what I want my variable to be at any particular time rather than relying on VBScript to decide what is best.

Comment: @TofuBug You should really use `&`. `&` already casts both types to a string so there's no need for unnecessary `CStr()` casting. The beauty of using typeless languages is that you don't have to constantly coerce values between types. You're taking one of the best features away and treating it like a strongly-typed language, which is really just more work. `str12 = CStr("1") + CStr("2")` is overkill. You could argue that your code is more readable because you're being explicit about your types. I would argue the opposite. It's messier because you don't have a clear understanding of them.

Comment: @TofuBug (Ran out of characters in my last post!). You're right, though, it's a personal preference. And I don't mean to insult your preference. Just know that `&` _only_ does string concatenation. That's it. `+` is overloaded to handle integer and real arithmetic as well as string concatenation so, unless you're diligent about using `CStr()` everywhere, there's a chance you may not get what you want.

Comment: @Bond Not to get into a flame war over this but I have a VERY clear understanding on how & works and how the Cxxx functions work my point is that just blindly relying on the & is not a good method. Say your code is pulling in a registry dword value and you are adding it to another integer later in your code. and you are writing out that value. Now the next version of a program changes that reg value to a string type your & of course will continue to work but your + to the existing integer just stops working.

Comment: @bond to continue: Yes & is a cool feature but when you work in an environment where things can and do change it can lead to confusion later especially when someone new has to come update existing vbscript code without any access to the systems that produce the variables values and having most of them working in notepad with no kind of debugger to speak of. Just cause a language gives you a variant type with all these back ground auto conversions does not excuse someone from being clear in the code

Comment: @TofuBug I guess I don't understand your example. If you're pulling a dword from the registry and adding it to an integer, you'll of course want to use `+`. You can't use `&` for arithmetic. As for confusion for someone new coming to VBScript, I would argue that using `+` for concatenation when dealing with strings (that may or may not be numeric) is more confusing than just using `&`. With `+`, you have to guess ("Am I getting a sum or a concatenation?"). With `&`, you're always getting a concatenation.

Comment: @Bond Your last statement is exactly my point with & it is always string concatenation with automatic string conversion. with + by itself only you are right you would have to guess what it is but if you have + with the Cxxx conversion functions you can immediately look at the code and say that's adding two longs, or that's concatenating variables into a string.

Comment: @Bond I may be trying to "break" a functionality of the language by doing my own type coercion, but I have been burned especially taking over existing code with the vbscript automatic conversions e.g. expect a lng get an int, think a variable is a number find out its a string or because of the context its used in here it might auto convert to a string but over here to a lng. Sure i'm using it like a strongly typed language  but I like to be able to a year from now open up a vbscript and without a debugger be able to tell exactly what its doing right down to the types used and expected.